# proper package installation in Ubuntu

Tags: apt, ppa

I have read an introduction about PPA at [ubuntu PPA](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/ubuntu-ppa-technology-explained/) and would like to revise my habit of installation in Ubuntu:

So, when I come to a Web page, click download for Ubuntu/Linux version and install the package by double-click or run an install script. What type of installation is that? is that the cause of unmet dependencies sometimes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're installing Debian packages (`*.deb`), this won't result in unmet depencencies. APT does the same: It downloads the deb file from the Ubuntu archives (or other PPAs) and installs them. The difference is: APT resolves unmet dependencies automatically. If you got unmet dependencies after installing a deb file, run `apt-get install -f`. This will try to resolve all unmet dependencies for you.

Installation by script usually keeps its fingers from APT or deb files, mostly it just copies the downloaded files to the destination directory (and compiles them previously if needed)

So either way: Fix unmet dependencies with `apt-get install -f`